# How to dynamically allocate memory using MPI in C++ instead of C malloc/calloc?

Tags: c++, c, mpi

I am trying to write a parallel code in C++ employing MPI, however I only know how to allocate memory using the C commands, as malloc/calloc. The aim is to work with the identity matrix and decompose it among the MPI processes.

The identity matrix is created on the local workspace and then sent from local to rank 0 to be printed.

The pieces of codes that I have tried are:

Allocating memory using C language:

- calloc

```
// N is the matrix size (N x N)
int* A=( int* )calloc( local_N*N, sizeof(int) );
```

- malloc

```
typedef int row[N];
row *mat;

/* Dividing the number of rows to each processor*/

int n = N / size;

mat = (row *) malloc(n * sizeof(row));
```

Allocating memory using C++ language:

```
 int**  matrix = new int *[row];
```

I succeed to run on C programming language, how ever I would like to rewrite the code for C++.

Comment: Try to not use manual memory management *at all* in C++. Use containers and/or smart pointers instead.

Comment: Just use `std::vector` which will take responsibility of managing memory and behaves like dynamic size C-array.

Comment: What is N? Is it known at compile time?

Comment: @YanB. how this is a duplication? This is completely different question.

Comment: This is completely a different question. I am trying to figure out the comparison between dynamic allocation memory between C and C++ for a specific MPI problem.

Comment: @oblivion N is the matrix size (NxN)

Comment: @yan-b It was your comment that generated the following message: "This question may already have an answer here: Can i allocate memory faster by using multiple threads? " and added a negative point ? It does not make sense.

Comment: @Alambek dynamic no? You most likely need a contiguous array which you want to know the pattern. An easier way is to just flatten your data and use vector. I'll write some when I reach my computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite handy to have contiguous array working with `MPI` specially it is much easier to code with contiguous data e.g. to make [derived data types](http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/mpi-data.html#Deriveddatatypes). My recommendation is using `vector` and flattening your data:

```
const int N = 100;
const int M = 20;
const int size = 4;
int n = N / size;
std::vector<int> mat(n*M); // each process has a mat with length of n * M
for(uint32_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    for(uint32_t j = 0; j < M; ++j)
        mat.at(i * M + j) = j; // this is equivalent to mat[i][j] if mat was 2D
```

You can also use [smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers)s:

```
using ManagedInt = std::unique_ptr<int[]> ;
auto managedMat = std::unique_ptr<ManagedInt[]>(new ManagedInt[n]);
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    managedMat[i] = ManagedInt(new int[M]);

for(uint32_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    for(uint32_t j = 0; j < M; ++j)
       managedMat[i][j] = j;
```

The bad way is:

**WARNING** you are about to enter ***programmer land.

```
// allocate mat
int **mat = new int *[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    mat[i] = new int [M];
}

// now you can use mat[i][j]

// delete mat
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    delete[] mat[i];
}
delete[] mat;
```

and the [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/2R-ClW)