# Initialize all elements in matrix with variable dimensions to zero

Tags: c++

I'm trying to initialize an `int` matrix in C++, with user-inputted dimensions, with every element set to zero. I know [there are some elegant ways to do that with a one-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-all-members-of-an-array-to-the-same-value) so I was wondering if there are any similar ways to do it with a two-dimensional array without using `for` loops and iterating through every element.

I found [a source](https://www.techiedelight.com/initialize-matrix-cpp/) that gave several different ways, including  `std::fill` (I've modified the code so that the dimensions are read with `cin`):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int x;
  cin >> x;
  int matrix[x][x];

  fill(*matrix, *matrix + x * 3, 0);

  for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

But why does this work, and why would the pointer to the matrix in the arguments for `fill` be necessary if it's not necessary for a one-dimensional array? That source said it was because matrixes in C++ are treated like one-dimensional arrays, which would make sense, but that is why I don't understand why the pointer is needed.

---

I don't know if this is relevant, but in case it can help, I've described my previous attempts below.

At first I thought I could initialize all elements to zero like in a one-dimensional array. For the matrix, this worked fine when the side lengths were not read with `cin` (i.e. when I declared the matrix as `int matrix[3][3] = {{}};` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520880/initializing-entire-2d-array-with-one-value)) but when I tried getting the side lengths from `cin` I started getting errors.

This was my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int x;
  cin >> x;
  int matrix[x][x] = {{}};

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

And when I tried to compile it, it threw this error:

```
matrix_test.cpp:7:14: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
  int matrix[x][x] = {{}};
             ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: `int matrix[x][x];` is not legal in standard `c++` by the rules of the standard the variable `x` must be a compile time constant. Here is why VLAs are not part of the standard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard

Comment: *But why does this work,* -- This does not compile `cin >> x; int matrix[x][x];` with the compiler I'm using (Visual Studio 2019), so there is no way for it to work.

Comment: Suggestion: [Use something like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301) By default it will zero all elements. If you want to change the default value, `Matrix::Matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols, double def)
: mRows(rows),
  mCols(cols),
  mData(rows * cols, def)
{
}`

Comment: this answer should help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/56907315/10933809

Comment: As for what went wrong, since the size is variable, the compiler is not able to generate initialization code to zero the array at compile time. It could generate code to do the initialization at run time, but what's the fun in doing that?

Comment: [An answer if you cannot use `std::vector`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm using the GCC compiler, version 4.2.1, from the terminal — not sure if that makes a difference, but for some reason the code works for me.

And thank you to everybody for all the helpful resources!

Comment: Unrelated: GCC 4.2.1, wowzers. That's almost as bad as the GCC 3.3.1 I need to use for a few legacy projects from the early 2000s. I assume you're stuck with that moldy old <expletive deleted> and can't upgrade to something a decade newer?

Comment: Uh, no, sorry, I'm just a beginner and didn't know anything better. It just came pre-installed on my computer and that's all I ever learned. Thanks for letting me know I could do with something better.

Comment: Not knowing what your computer is, I can't make good suggestions on how to upgrade GCC. In Linux, it could be a matter of asking the package manager for GCC 8 or 9. In Windows [follow along with this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071634/4581301). On a Mac... That's one damn old Mac. I dunno how you'd update it.

Comment: It's a mac, unfortunately. Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why you're getting the error

c-style arrays (such as `int matrix[3][3]`) must have size specified at the point you declare it. They can't vary in size in C++.

#### What you could do instead.

If you use `std::vector`, there's a really elegant way to do it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace std; 

    int x;
    cin >> x;

    auto matrix = vector<vector<int>>(x, vector<int>(x, 0)); 

    // This is how we can print it
    for(auto& row : matrix) {
        for(auto& elem : row) {
            cout << elem << ' '; 
        }
        cout << '\n'; 
    }
}
```

In C++17, you can shorten this even further:

```
    auto matrix = vector(x, vector(x, 0));
```

What `vector(number, thing)` means is "Create a vector of *number*, where each element is *thing*".

Comment: Not quite true. The compiler the Asker is using does allow variable length arrays, but it does not allow you to initialize a variable length array.

Answer (score 0):

The second dimension of two-dimension array must be a compile time constant, but in your code `x` is not.

Actually if you write a function with a two-dimension parameter, the second dimension must also be a compile time constant. That's because the array is stored linearly in the memory and the compiler must know the second dimension to calculate the offset correctly.

Comment: As another answer mentioned, using `std::vector` is an elegant way.